# Is it ok to derive from System.ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, exception

If I have a method that checks the validity of its arguments, is it ok to throw my own custom exceptions derived from `System.ArgumentException`? I am asking because `ArgumentException` is itself derived from `System.SystemException` and I am seeing conflicting guidelines as to whether an application should derive from `SystemException`. (Albeit indirectly, deriving from `ArgumentException` is still tantamount to deriving from `SystemException`.)

I see lots of guidelines saying don't derive from `ApplicationException`, but derive from Exception instead. I'm happy with that. What I'm not sure about is whether it's ok to derive from SystemException too.

If I shouldn't derive from `SystemException`, then what should I derive my `"invalid argument"` exception classes from?

Comment: If the supplied parameters are not valid, the method is expected to throw an `ArgumentException`. You can perfectly derive from it to use in such cases. Deriving from `SystemException` doesn't make sense but you throw an `ArgumentNullException` if an argument is null or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if it's outside the acceptable range. They both are derived from `ArgumentException`. So throwing a custom exception which is not derived from `ArgumentException` in such cases is IMHO something that you *shouldn't* do. So I'd go with Botz3000's answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [MSDN page about Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> Throw an ArgumentException or a class derived from ArgumentException
>   if invalid parameters are passed.

So i would say it's ok and even recommended.

Answer (score 7):

One benefit of deriving from System.ArgumentException is that `catch(System.ArgumentException)` blocks will be able to handle your custom exception type as well as `System.ArgumentException`. This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to derive your "invalid argument" exceptions and they don't have a meaning beyond that, then `ArgumentException` sounds like a reasonable candidate:

> **ArgumentException** is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of the called method. [--MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The original idea behind exceptions in .Net was that exceptions in the base class libraries (e.g. the System assemblies) would throw exceptions which derived from `System.Exception` and advised that all custom exceptions inherit from `System.ApplicationException` to differentiate between BCL exceptions and application exceptions however Microsoft have backtracked on this idea and now suggest that all exceptions inherit from `System.Exception`.

My advice is to inherit from the lowest `Exception` class in the framework that makes sense.

If your exception means something specific other than there is a problem with this argument, e.g. the type can add semantics to the exception (just as `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` do) then make a custom one, if not then just use `ArgumentException` and supply a meaningful exception message.

Comment: User exceptions were supposed to derive from ApplicationException, not SystemException.

Comment: Well spotted, I typed exception too often in that post, I'll correct it!

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% reusing the ArgumentException properties and add some extra functionality it, it would be ok. However when you only reuse it because of its name, it would not be ok.